# how to make a shuffle animation for a view in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

so this event gets triggered in the code on shake movement.

```
    void _shakeDetector_ShakeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            ShuffleView();
        });
    }
```

now this view has a grid(ContentPanel) which contains only images for which i need a shuffle animation...

any references in this direction would be helpful...

Comment: are the images of equal sizes? Are you using a wrap panel?

Comment: yes all the images are of equal size(w X h) & there is no wrap panel used.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not being specific with code, but this is a general direction in which I would go to have the shuffle effect.

Since the images are all the same size and assuming that they are shown in a structured grid or list (It will be easier if it is a list), you could run a Translate animation on the images. See [this book](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/) for animations, it is a good resource for learning animations on silverlight.

You have to locate the centers (or, any convenient coordinates) of the images and translate the images. So if every image is 10px high, and organized in a list, with a margin of 5px between the images, then every image's center's coordinate will be (x, y+(n*15)). (You don't really need x, in a list of images)

For the shuffle, a randomization of this sequence of animation(and the coordinates of the final position of the images) would be necessary, hence you'll have to write the code for this.

This is just a suggestion, hope it helps.